# Using MSBUILD with C++ Builder 2010

Tags: msbuild, c++builder

Enlighten me please... I have a buildserver that runs **MSBUILD** to build projects done in **C++ Builder 2010**. I wanted to setup that entire setup on my local machine to be able to work on the build scripts without messing up the live build server. But I was wondering how MSBUILD knew how to work with C++ Builder projects.

Then I read that a file called **Borland.Group.Targets** was the magic piece. But I can't find it anywhere. I looked at **Embarcaderos site, Microsoft's site, the C++ builder and MSBUILD installations** etc. What is it, where do I get it and how does it work?

*(My guess is that it's a file with "rules" telling MSBUILD how to handle C++ Builder projects, but that doesn't help if I can't find the file... hehe)*

Comment: look for files like these: *.targets, *.proj. Usually the proj file includes a reference to the targets file. The instructions to perform the actual "build" are usually in the targets file. But, if you run a continuous integration piece of software, it can get more complicated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to build a project via the command line? Make a .cmd file like so:

```
@ECHO OFF
call rsvars.bat

msbuild.exe MyProject.cbproj /t:clean /p:Config=Release
msbuild.exe MyProject.cbproj /t:build /p:Config=Release
```

Comment: No, I'm looking to make C++ Builder projects compile using msbuild xml scripts.

Comment: Update: I read a bit more about it and understood that C++ builder actually use MSBUILD nowadays :P